# How to write recursive iterator without using itertools?

Tags: python, recursion, iterator, permutation

I need to write recursive iterator permutations(n) without using itertools, but I don't know what I need to write in the recursive part of the code. Now it looks like this:

```
def permutations(n):
    if n == 0:
        yield []
    else :
        for i in permutations(n-1):
```

```
for i in permutations(2): print(i)
```

Output of this line should be [0,1], [1,0].
What I need to add in my code?

Comment: what is the expected out of `permutations(3)`?

Comment: Happily the docs for `permutations` has an example implementation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: @anwarvic it should be [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]. Order of lists doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your purpose.

```
def permutations(n):
    yield from permut((), tuple(range(n)))
​
​
def permut(left, right):
    if not right:
        yield left
​
    for i, elem in enumerate(right):
        yield from permut((*left, elem), (*right[:i], *right[i+1:]))
```